# Spark 2.3.1 support for Java 10

Tags: apache-spark

I have installed Java 10, Scala 2.12.6 and spark 2.3.1 in my desktop having Ubuntu 16.04. I am getting error opening spark-shell.

Failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
Please let me know if there is any way to run spark in Java 10.

Comment: Spark doesn't announce for their official support for Java 10.

Comment: Thanks Praveen, can you please let me know till which version of Java Spark have officially announced?

Comment: Upto Java 8, they have officially announced. Please find in their installation documentation. Java 9, shows some inconsistencies while boot-strapping the spark-shell. It is better recommended to use Java 8, until they officially announce the support for Java 9 and 10. You can always check with their official site.

Comment: I believe they will officially announce the support for Java 10 rather than Java 9, As many community is slowly withdrawing support for Java 9. You can also find in http://start.spring.io/  only two versions of Java, they have 8 and 10. It doesn't mean that they didn't support for Java 9. You can wait from Spark Official community to announce their support.

Comment: Thanks Praveen. I appreciate you help!!